# How can I assign <SuperKey>+<N> to invoke Nautilus?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, shortcut-keys

Someone was recently chatting about using <kbd>Super Key</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>to call up `Explorer` in Ubuntu and I joked "Why don't you use <kbd>Super Key</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>?" (for file manager) but when I tried that combination it was already assigned by Ubuntu for `Files` search.

So then I tried <kbd>Super Key</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and discovered it wasn't assigned yet. The other chatter had left the chat room so I couldn't ask how it is done. How can I assign <kbd>Super Key</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to call up Nautilus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.

1. Go to Settings-> Keyboard->Shortcuts-> Custom. Click <kbd>+</kbd> button.
2. Assign name to it and add command `nautilus`. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd>
   [image]
3. Click on *Disabled* to input a key combination. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd> 
   [image]

**And done !**

Comment: I couldn't find the "OK" button, can I click "Apply" instead?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yes, that was my mistake. Apply button it is. I edited my post just now

Comment: Works perfectly as long as "Nautilus" is spelled in lower case as "nautilius".